# Lossless tiff images change when read and written after the first one in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have run into a problem that I can't explain not understand why it is happening. I have a set of images in the `.tiff` format that I read using the `PIL` library in Python. The images, save for the first one, change. This change is not visible to the naked eye but checking their hashes reveal their unwanted morphosis.

I would like for them to not change when written back into `.tiff` files if any modification has not been made to the NumPy array containing that respective image.

#### Code:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import glob
import hashlib


def open_images_into_array_conc(file_path):
    """Read a single image into an NumPy array and return it along with the shape."""
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    pixel_array = np.array(image)
    return pixel_array.flatten(), pixel_array.shape

def open_images_into_array_sync(file_path):
    """Read multiple images in the file path into an array and return said array."""
    image_paths = glob.glob(file_path)

    pixel_array_list = []
    pixel_array_shape_list = []
    for image_path in image_paths:
        pixel_array, pixel_array_shape = open_images_into_array_conc(image_path)
        pixel_array_list.append(pixel_array)
        pixel_array_shape_list.append(pixel_array_shape)
    return pixel_array_list, pixel_array_shape_list

def main():
    # Read the matching images in the folder and prepare an array of images and of their corresponding shapes. 
    pixel_array_list, pixel_array_shape_list = open_images_into_array_sync("scikit_image/cover/cover_*.tiff")
    pixel_array_sizes = (pixel_array.size for pixel_array in pixel_array_list)

    # Create a NumPy array of images and flatten all images for processing.
    pixel_arrays = np.array(pixel_array_list)
    pixel_arrays_flat = np.concatenate(pixel_arrays)

    stego_pixel_arrays = pixel_arrays_flat  # Image processing is done here. Left out to demonstrate the problem.

    # Rebuild images from a flat NumPy array.
    stego_pixel_array_list = []
    previous_index = 0
    for (index, pixel_array_shape) in zip(pixel_array_sizes, pixel_array_shape_list):
        stego_pixel_array = stego_pixel_arrays[previous_index:previous_index + index].reshape(pixel_array_shape)
        stego_pixel_array_list.append(stego_pixel_array)
        previous_index += index

    # Write images back into .tiff files.
    for index, (stego_pixel_array, pixel_array_shape) in enumerate(zip(stego_pixel_array_list, pixel_array_shape_list)):
        output_image = Image.fromarray(stego_pixel_array.reshape(pixel_array_shape), mode="RGB")
        output_image.save(f"scikit_image/stego/stego_{index + 1}.tiff")

    # Read the written image files and check their hash.
    stego_pixel_array_list, stego_pixel_array_shape_list = open_images_into_array_sync(
            "scikit_image/stego/stego_*.tiff")
    stego_pixel_array_sizes = (pixel_array.size for pixel_array in stego_pixel_array_list)

    stego_pixel_arrays = np.array(stego_pixel_array_list)

    print(hashlib.sha256(pixel_arrays).digest())  # Cover images' hash.
    print(hashlib.sha256(stego_pixel_arrays).digest())  # Stego images' hash.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have used `ffmpeg` to compute the md5 hashes of all the images in thier respective folder.

#### Commands used:

Cover Folder.

```
ffmpeg -v error -i cover_%d.tiff -f framehash -hash md5 -

0,          0,          0,        1,  4665600, 74088845b7259505b55e83271e627d64
0,          1,          1,        1,  4665600, 710c9adb44062c8efaf28cdedf5fb3ec
0,          2,          2,        1,  4665600, f106932ea53d6314b635ad69a9c80c9b
0,          3,          3,        1,  4665600, b9d1ae8223baaa2abdb6e33fd75c4210
0,          4,          4,        1,  4665600, 3d2834aeaed24c4b6d3b5481689e7858
...
```

Stego Folder.

```
ffmpeg -v error -i stego_%d.tiff -f framehash -hash md5 -

0,          0,          0,        1,  4665600, 74088845b7259505b55e83271e627d64
0,          1,          1,        1,  4665600, b48df8ce73737cb5a5838b8986f49f1c
0,          2,          2,        1,  4665600, a3825390ba3e29a1aca9518cf67e7b8d
0,          3,          3,        1,  4665600, ba5a3cc93d62d5be8efd2bddca7103b7
0,          4,          4,        1,  4665600, 75f3f9056942f8b402ff23b263b2ae1a
...
```

I have included the first 5 hashes from output images of both `cover` and `stego` folders and all but the first one do not match. To my understanding, `.tiff` format files are a lossless container for images and this should not be happening. I have also taken the output images in the `stego` folder and placed that into the input `cover` folder and reran the test. All hashes save for the first one change. Thank you for your time and guidance and I apologize if I made any mistake in asking the question. I will rectify any mistake that I am pointed towards.

#### Update

The problem only occurs whenever the image count is equal to 10 or higher.

#### Update 2

I have modified the code to show the hashes of all the images while they are in the NumPy array so that they can be compared during runtime.

Comment: There are many possible reasons... I suggest you to replace your input Tiffs with the output Tiffs saved in Python (just rename the files), and repeat the test.

Comment: I have done that. Sorry for not stating that explicitly. The hashes after the first one just change into something different.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. **1.** Create some sample tiff files: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=5:size=640x480:rate=1 cover_im%d.tiff` **2.** Execute your python code. **3.** compute hash: `ffmpeg -v error -i cover_im%d.tiff -f framehash -hash md5 - ` and `ffmpeg -v error -i stego_%d.tiff -f framehash -hash md5 - `. All the hashes are equal.

Comment: This is very weird. I cannot reproduce the problem on my end too.... till I tried using `testsrc=duration=10` to generate 10 images. All the hashes match up to using 9 images. Then they stop matching on my end. Can you try using 10 or more images on your devide? Thank you for taking the time to do this.

Comment: You should not compare the TIFF files, but the image stored in it. Save the image to TIFF, load it in again, compare the two arrays. The TIFF container can have a lot of additional, optional information that doesn’t affect the image data itself, that you can easily change to modify the checksum, without affecting the image data.

Comment: Use few digits with leading zeros. Like %03d   Set file names to end with 001.tiff, 002.tiff ...

Comment: @CrisLuengo The arrays are not the same. I hashed the raw NumPy arrays and they are different from one another.

Comment: @Rotem This is working. I would like to accept your answer as the solution if you would kindly post it as an answer. Can I ask why this is the case and how you came to this solution? I would like to learn and Thank You again for the answer.

Comment: LOL. If Rotem’s solution works, it’s because of the file order? You were comparing the wrong files with each other?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I doesn't seem like it. I directly hashed the frames after reading them into memory after reading your comment. They differed on my end and I could not get them to match. Even if FFmpeg was reading them in the 'wrong' order, I don't see how Python would do the same.

Comment: I decided not to post an answer. It's difficult to phrase a good answer for your question. The main issue is how to use FFmpeg, and it's little out of topic.

Comment: change ---> stego_pixel_array = stego_pixel_arrays[previous_index:previous_index + index].reshape(pixel_array_shape) to ---> stego_pixel_array = stego_pixel_arrays[previous_index:previous_index + index +1].reshape(pixel_array_shape)

Comment: @Rotem To my understanding, FFmpeg has been used to diagnose and show the problem of the images changing after being written. It may or may not be a Python issue. As I have stated in an earlier comment. Reading the images into a NumPy array, writing it back and reading it again results in a different array from the first one due to the ways files have been named. I would argue FFmpeg is nothing but a mere tool to demonstrate the problem. Can you share how you would have asked the question if you don't mind? So, that I may use it as a reference in the future to ask better questions.

Comment: **1.** The question should include minimal reproducible code sample. You can simply read and write the Tiff files in a simple loop. **2.** You may ask how to compare the input and output hash using FFmpeg by executing it as a sub-process and reading the result from stdout pipe (sdtout pipe of the sub-process). **3.** You may write that you know how to get the hash using the command line tool, but you have a problem: the names of the Tiff files are without sequential numbers.

Comment: TIFF is not necessarily lossless, it can be lossy. Please show the output from `exiftool` run on one of your images that gets the wrong hash.